# JQuery Checkbox passing variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="acctsEdit_57" value="0"> Weekly
<input type="checkbox" name="acctsEdit_57" value="1"> BI Weekly
Collection : 2
<input type="checkbox" name="acctsEdit_58" value="0"> Weekly
<input type="checkbox" name="acctsEdit_58" value="1"> BI Weekly
```

Collection : 1 
 Weekly
 BI Weekly
Collection : 2
 Weekly
 BI Weekly

I have list of checkboxes with the values, in JQuery, when the user submit, I have to retrieve the list of checked values.
I need to pass ID paratmert in the Jquery , in order to get list of checkbox values.

```js
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
var selectedBillingCycleEdit = [];

$.each($("input[name='acctsEdit_57']:checked"), function()
{      
                              selectedBillingCycleEdit.push($(this).val());
});
```

I tried to pass Id variable instead of _57,  can you please any one help me to resolve the issue.

```
   $.each($("input[name='acctsEdit_' + id]:checked")
```

I tried to pass + id in the above, i am getting error.

Comment: `$("input[name='acctsEdit_" + id + "']:checked")` concatenate string to create  a valid selector

Comment: you are great!  Thanks a lot. its working.

Comment: Why do you use `type=checkbox` instead of `type=radio`?